# Import csv file in sqlite3 from iphone.

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, csv

**How to create any application in iPhone for import csv file into sqlite3. Any Example, suggestion or any help please.**

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform the following steps to import csv into sqlite3 database

1. Add the file into your resources folder.(Suppose the name of file is "List.csv")
2. First get the path of CSV file.

   ```
   NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"List" ofType:@"csv"];
   ```
3. Write the following method to parse and insert in database.

   ```
   [self insertIntoDatabaseFromFile:path];
   ```
4. The method goes as follows

   ```
   -(void)insertIntoDatabaseFromFile:(NSString*)path
   {

    NSString *fileDataString=[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    //Gives u the array with all lines separated by new line.
    NSArray *linesArray=[fileDataString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\r"];
    int k = 0;
    for (id string in linesArray){

       //Gives u the number of items in one line separated by comma(,)
       NSString *lineString=[linesArray objectAtIndex:k];

       //Gives u the array of all components.
       NSArray *columnArray=[lineString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

      //Get elements from array and create a query to add all into database.
      //Write your code for that.

      k++;

   }
   ```